# show second Dialog if someone does not input text into the first Dialog within a timefrate?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

I have made a dialog appear which can be closed if someone correctly types in a certain word. I wanted to know if it was possible to make a second dialog appear if someone does not type anything into the first text box within a certain timeframe. For example, if the person does not input text within the next 5 minutes, is there any way to trigger a second dialog to show up?

```
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Your time finished'),
                content: Text('Type "OKAY" if you want to go back to the homepage'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _textEditingController,
                        validator: (String? word){
                          if (word != OKAY){
                            _NoDialog();
                          }
                          else{
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
      });
```

I called the function `NoDialog` if the text the person gives is incorrect, but I am not sure how to make an 'if' statement if the person does not put anything in the text box for a certain period of time.
I think I could do an 'if' statement if the person leaves the text blank and then call a new function with a Future.delayed attached, but I couldnt find a way to make an 'if' statement for the case when no text is entered. Also in this case, I believe the person would have to hit the 'enter' key, but I want the second dialog to show up because the user has not touched anything on the screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple case, you can show nested-overlap dialog with passing same the build-context.

The First dialog will be

```dart
_userInputCheckerDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String correctText,
    Duration maxTime = const Duration(seconds: 2),
  }) async {
    bool _noInteraction = true;

    /// apear if user doesnt type anything within
    Future.delayed(maxTime).then((t) async {
      if (_noInteraction) await _showSecondDialog(context);
    });
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          ///may need in future to change variable inside dialog
          builder: (context, setStateSB) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) async {
                  _noInteraction = false;
                  if (value == correctText) {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pop(); // close after getting currect text
                  }
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Then the inner dialog is having the same context

```dart
  _showSecondDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
        content: Text("Hey start typing"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> this is only checking 1st time of user interaction.

If you want to use timeframe, we need to use  [async package](https://pub.dev/packages/async) to cancel (not really cancelling) the future.
You might feel it a little more complicated than the 1st one.

**Use async**

```dart
  _showSecondDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
        content: Text("Hey start typing"),
      ),
    );
  }

  CancelableOperation _restartTimer({
    CancelableOperation? cancelableOperation,
    Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 4),
    required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    if (cancelableOperation != null) {
      cancelableOperation.cancel();
      cancelableOperation = null;
    }
    cancelableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
      Future.delayed(
        duration,
      ),
    ).then((p0) async {
      await _showSecondDialog(context);
    });

    return cancelableOperation;
  }

  _userInputCheckerDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String correctText,
    Duration maxTime = const Duration(seconds: 2),
  }) async {
    CancelableOperation? _cancelableOperation;

    ///start timer at startUp
    _cancelableOperation = _restartTimer(
      context: context,
      cancelableOperation: _cancelableOperation,
      duration: maxTime,
    );

    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          ///may need in future to change variable inside dialog
          builder: (context, setStateSB) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) async {
                  _cancelableOperation = _restartTimer(
                      context: context,
                      cancelableOperation: _cancelableOperation);
                  if (value == correctText) {
                    _cancelableOperation!.cancel();
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pop(); // close after getting currect text
                  }
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```